# Переадресация ссылки через HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день, у меня есть такая вот интересная задача:
Клиент подгружает фото напрямую с чужого сервера, но он хочет чтобы ссылки были такие, якобы изображения лежат у него; первое, что пришло в голову это обернуть все это дело в htaсcess, но я понятия не имею как это правильно сделать.
Для понимания. Есть изображение, имеющее ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/upfiles/logo.png
Надо, чтобы у клиента оно открывалось по ссылке [http://мой-сайт.ру/uploadMyFile/logo.png](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/uploadMyFile/logo.png)

PS: Изображения могут быть как на HTTP, так и на HTTPS.
Заранее спасибо за поддержку, подсказки и полезные материалы =) (возможно и за решение тоже :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через htaccess не получится. Можно с помощью PHP:

```
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    //Определяем расширение картинки
    $extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    switch($extension)
    {
    case 'jpg':
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        break;
    case 'png':
        header("Content-Type: image/png");
        break;
    case 'gif'
        header("Content-Type: image/gif");
        break;
    default:
        'Такой файл не поддерживается!';
        exit;
    }
    //Выводим саму картинку
    readfile($url);
```

И потом обращаешься к этому файлу: http://mysite.ru/image.php?url=URL_картики_с_другого_сервера

А уже через htaccess настройте, чтобы открывалось так:
http://мой-сайт.ру/uploadMyFile/URL_картинки
Думаю сами знаете как это сделать, через RewriteRule. Что-то вроде такого будет:

```
RewriteRule ^uploadMyFile/(.*)$ image.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Не плохое решение, как Вариант сойдет, но я предпочту подождать до вечера, может-быть для других участников #ХешКода кто-нибудь ещё вариантов выложит.